# I can't use " If "

Tags: dart

```
DataBase db =  DataBase();
bool result= db.connect();
if (result){
  print("It connected");

}else{
  print("It doesn't match");
}


class DataBase {
  String username = "asd";
  int password = 1234;
  bool connect() {
    if (username == "asd" && password == 1234) {
      return true;
    } else
      return false;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to learn dart language. I'm having a problem with using " If " in here. I wanna use " If " for result but it says "if' can't be used as an identifier because it's a keyword.
Try renaming this to be an identifier that isn't a keyword.".

Comment: You code looks right. Can you paste the stacktrace (the one in console which says error)?

Comment: @Rahul - sounds more like a compile error than a runtime error so no stacktrace or?

Comment: Thank you for answering. The error on console is:  "A function declaration needs an explicit list of parameters.
Try adding a parameter list to the function declaration."

Comment: I have a problem in here:
 if (result){
  print("It connected");

}else{
  print("It doesn't match");
}

Comment: i don't know dart. but isn't your connect function supposed to be a static bool

Comment: also you call it like. Database db = new Database(); //cmiw

Comment: Oh my bad. I figured  that i didnt write these in main list. I fixed it. I'm sorry. It' is easy to miss these small details for me. I will do my best. Thank you for your comments friends.

Answer (score 3):

it's because you use it outside the main method, try to put it into main like this:

```
void main() {
    DataBase db =  DataBase();
    bool result= db.connect();
    if (result) {
        print("It connected");
    } else {
        print("It doesn't match");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `main` function:

[image]

Comment: Please do not share code as an image. Put the code in your answer. Further information is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/407041